# Generating matrix with omp causes trouble, different columsizes

Tags: c++, matrix, openmp

i've got a problem and a question.
I tried to make some matrix multiplication with omp.

If i create the matrices a, b, and c with more than one thread, the colum sizes aren't equal.
The problem remains even if i use critical for push_back.
I thought omp divide the for loop in equal sized pieces, so every thread should have his own column. Is the problem in ?

What is a good way to give every thread a vector?
And what is a good way to avoid shared memory problems without critical and atomic, e.g. if i'm generating data and want to save it somewhere.
Thanks.
P.S. I am working on my english. It 's far away from perfect, so please don't mind.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <omp.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
#include <vector>

#define NRA 300                /* number of rows in matrix A */
#define NCA 300              /* number of columns in matrix A */
#define NCB 300                  /* number of columns in matrix B */

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int i, j, k, chunk;

    std::vector < std::vector<int> > a;
    a.resize(NRA);
    std::vector < std::vector<int> > b;
    b.resize(NCA);
    std::vector < std::vector<int> > c;
    c.resize(NRA);
    /*
    double a[NRA][NCA];
    double b[NCA][NCB];
    double c[NRA][NCB];
    */
    chunk = 10;                    

    std::clock_t start;         //Zeitmessung
    double duration;            //Zeitdauer der Parallelisierung


        omp_set_num_threads(4);
#pragma omp parallel
        {
#pragma omp for schedule (static, chunk) 
            for (i = 0; i < NRA; i++)
                for (j = 0; j < NCA; j++)
                    a[i].push_back(i + j);
#pragma omp for schedule (static, chunk)
            for (i = 0; i < NCA; i++)
                for (j = 0; j < NCB; j++)
                    b[i].push_back(i*j);
#pragma omp for ordered schedule(static, chunk)
            for (i = 0; i < NRA; i++)
                for (j = 0; j < NCB; j++)
                    c[i].push_back(0);
        }

    for (int nthreads = 1; nthreads < 40; nthreads++)
    {
        start = std::clock();
        omp_set_dynamic(0);
#pragma omp parallel shared(a,b,c,nthreads,chunk) private(i,j,k) num_threads(nthreads)
    {

#pragma omp for schedule (static, chunk)
        for ( i = 0; i < NRA; i++)
            for (j = 0; j < NCB; j++)
                c[i][j] = 0;

#pragma omp for ordered schedule (static, chunk) 
        for (i = 0; i < NRA; i++)
        {
            for ( j = 0; j < NCB; j++)
                for (k = 0; k < NCA; k++)
                    c[i][j] += a[i][k] * b[k][j];
        }
    }   

        duration = (std::clock() - start) / (double)CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
        //Time n threads need
        std::cout << "Benoetigte Zeit fuer " << nthreads << " Threads betrug " << duration << " Sekunden." << std::endl;
    }

    std::cin.get();

}
```

Comment: `push_back()` definitely modifies vector’s metadata, especially size. I’d try to `resize()` the inner vectors like you do with the outer ones (`a`, `b`, `c`) and then just modify the elements (`a[i] = i + j;` etc.) in the parallel run.

Comment: Thank you! It works. Is vector in vector a good way to store data from every thread?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`push_back()` definitely modifies vector’s metadata, especially size. Try to `resize()` the inner vectors like you do with the outer ones (`a`, `b`, `c`) and then just modify the elements (`a[i] = i + j;` etc.) in the parallel run.

Since you know the final count of elements in the beginning, you can use plain arrays instead of vectors to minimize overhead.

```
int a[NRA][NCA];
int b[NCA][NCB];
int c[NRA][NCB];
```

I wonder why you’ve commented out the similar part of your code. ;-)

Comment: Because i was playing with omp. ^^
To learn something new. And i learned something new.
Anyway. Thank you

Comment: I know large my inner vectors are. What can I do, if i don't know their length?

Comment: Use vectors and resize them. Resizing must happen in a critical section, so only one thread can modify the vector metadata at any time. For performance reasons, you should prefer resizing in bigger portions at once (`push_back()` only adds one element at a time). Or there can be one thread per vector, so they will run independently.